# how to compare key/value from array and update different value exists

Tags: javascript

I have two array arr1 and arr2 from where I need to check if arr1 having same key with different value then arr1 updates the arr2's value.

```
const arr1 = [{
        text: 'status',
        value: 'status',
        hide: false,
        validate: true,
        sort: true
    },
    {
        text: 'address',
        value: 'add',
        hide: false,
        validate: true,
        sort: true
    },
    {
        text: 'Last Name',
        value: 'lname',
        hide: false,
        validate: true,
        sort: true
    },
    {
        text: 'First Name',
        value: 'fname',
        hide: false,
        validate: true,
        sort: true
    },
    {
        text: 'age',
        value: 'age',
        hide: false,
        validate: true,
        sort: true
    },
];

const arr2 = [{
        text: 'status',
        value: 'status',
        show: false
    },
    {
        text: 'address',
        value: 'add',
        show: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Last Name',
        value: 'lname',
        show: false
    },
    {
        text: 'First Name',
        value: 'fname',
        show: true
    },
];
```

update the arr1 if value matched in both array update the rest value. for example status matched then arr1 should be {text: 'status', value: 'status', hide: true, show: false, validate: true, sort: true}.

Hide value gets true because show value false if show value is true and hide will be false.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's important that you show your work here so people can help clear up the bits you don't understand or are getting wrong. Just asking for people to figure it out for you generally will yield less help and likely get the question closed. What have you tried?

Comment: Make an object whose keys are the text values, and values are the objects. Then you can loop through the other array and update the elements with the matching key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking every single property, I just merged object, to get values of the second array, and stored it inside a new array.

```js
let arrayMerged = arr1.map((el1) => {
  // Looking for matching element in arr2
  let matchingElement = arr2.find((el2) => el2.text == el1.text);

  // Make changes if element was found in second arr
  if (matchingElement) {
    // Here you can write some logic to change properties values, like e.g. hide
    // in case show/hide i wouldn't even check if they are different, just update accordingly
    el1.hide = !matchingElement.show;
    return { ...el1, ...matchingElement }; // Objects are merged
  } else {
    // else return untouched object
    return el1;
  }
});
```

Output:

```js
{text: 'status', value: 'status', hide: true, validate: true, sort: true, …}
{text: 'address', value: 'add', hide: true, validate: true, sort: true, …}
{text: 'Last Name', value: 'lname', hide: true, validate: true, sort: true, …}
{text: 'First Name', value: 'fname', hide: false, validate: true, sort: true, …}
{text: 'age', value: 'age', hide: false, validate: true, sort: true}
```